# Solving of differential equations by manipulating differentials

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to learn how to solve differential equations and in multiple tutorials differentials are manipulated by variables. I attempted to try it out on a ODE:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2y=x$$
I multiplied both sides by dx,
$$dy+x^2ydx=xdx$$
$$dy=(x-x^2y)dx$$
took an integral,
$$\int{dy}=\int{(x-x^2y)dx}$$
$$y=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{yx^3}{3}$$
$$6y+2yx^3=3x^2$$
$$y=\frac{3x^2}{6+2x^3}$$
I have checked the solution to this ODE in Wolfram and it produced something super complicated.
Can anyone inform me of any conceptual errors in my work and maybe teach me how to manipulate differentials? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You integration of $(x-x^2y)dx$ was not valid, as $y$ is still there.

Comment: the $y$ is a function of $x$ but you let it as constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y$ is an unknown function of $x$, there is no good way to determine what $\int x^2ydx$ might be.  The problem is not separable, so you can't separate the $x$'s on one side and the $y$'s on the other.  However, this is a first degree linear ODE which can be solved through integrating factors.  The integrating factor in this case turns out to be $e^{\frac13x^3}$.  Multiplying both sides by this yields

$$e^{\frac13x^3}y'+x^2e^{\frac13x^3}y=xe^{\frac13x^3}$$

The correct integrating factor allows us to use the product rule.  The equation can be rewritten as

$$\frac{d(e^{\frac13x^3}y)}{dx}=xe^{\frac13x^3}$$

Now we can integrate both sides with respect to $x$, keeping the constant of integration in mind.  I don't think the integral of the right hand side is elementary, but a solution can be given as

$$y=e^{-\frac13x^3}\int x^{\frac13x^3}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

As this is a linear ODE you can solve it using the idea, that the general solution is the superposition (sum) of the homogenous solution and the particular solution.

$$y'=-x^2y+x$$

The homogenous equation is:
$$y_h'=-x^2y_h$$

Integrating this yields:
$$y_h=ce^{-\frac{1}{3}x^3}$$

In order to get the particular solution we use the method of variation of constants.
$$y_p=y_hd(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{3}x^3}c\cdot d(x)$$
Note that $c\cdot d(x)$ is still an function of $x$, so we substitute $c\cdot d(x)=c(x)$. Now plug this into your ODE and realize that there are some cancelations:

$$c'(x)e^{-\frac{1}{3}x^3}=x$$
$$c(x)=\int xe^{\frac{1}{3}x^3}\mathrm{dx}$$

I guess that this integral has no closed form.

So the general solution is:

$$y=y_h+y_p=y_h+c(x)y_h=ce^{-\frac{1}{3}x^3}+e^{-\frac{1}{3}x^3}\int xe^{\frac{1}{3}x^3}\mathrm{dx}=e^{-\frac{1}{3}x^3}(c+\int xe^{\frac{1}{3}x^3}\mathrm{dx}) $$

Answer (score 0):

Normally this method works if you can separate stuff in $y$ from stuff from $x$, putting them on separate sides of the equality and then integrate.
In your case you are integrating $x^2ydx$ which contains $y$. This is the point in my opinion. You may try for example with
\begin{equation}
y\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2=x
\end{equation}
and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

If $y' + P(x)y = q(x)$ then $y=e^{-\int p(x) dx}(\int e^{\int p(x) dx}q(x) dx+c) $ is answer.

$y=e^{-\int x^2 dx}(\int e^{\int x^2dx}x dx+c)=e^{-\frac{x^3}{3}}(\int e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}x dx+c)$